# How to run/make open the Glassfish Server outside of IDE's

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish

I have download Glassfish 5.0 zip file(there was only zip file) for windows. I was able to install glassfish on intellij but i wanna start/run glassfish server outside of the ides. Glassfish becomes only running when i click "run" in ide

How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start GlassFish in Windows, you will need to open a `cmd` prompt at the directory where you unzipped GlassFish.

Once there, you should see a directory structure which includes `bin`, `glassfish`, `javadb` and `mq`.

Run the following command:

```
bin\asadmin.bat start-domain
```

GlassFish will start in the background. To stop GlassFish, run the following command from the same directory:

```
bin\asadmin.bat stop-domain
```

Pay attention to the output when GlassFish starts because it will tell you the location of the server.log file and other details.